# Tkinter: How to set the default new Text insert focus coordinates

Tags: python, tkinter

When moving the text insert off the screen such that new text comes onto the screen (as well as the text insert), how do I get the text insert to be focused on at a specified x,y coordinate instead of the middle of the screen? For instance, when I'm using pagedown, I would like it to focus on the text insert at the bottom of the screen (instead of the center). When I'm using pageup, I would like it to focus on the text insert at the top of the screen (instead of the center).

For clarification, the default behavior is that when pressing pageup or pagedown, the text insert is in the middle of the screen after the insert moves. I would like it to be at the top and bottom respectively (where possible, considering that pageup/pagedown does not always have an entire page to traverse). Any ideas on how to do this? I don't see any built-in methods for the purpose. `Text.see(myIndex)` allows for no x,y coordinates as far as the documentation says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor indicates the insert position or the text 'insert' mark within the text.  With Win7, 2.7.8 (tk 8.5.15) and 3.4.2 (tk 8.6.1), I see the following behavior.

If the cursor is visible, PageUp/Down move both the cursor and the text Up/Down a page, so the cursor appears to stay still, with the text moving under it.

If the cursor in not visible, because of scrolling, PageUP/Down move the page and put the cursor ('insert' mark) at the upper left corner of the page.  (This is different from what you describe and may depend on the system or Python or tk version.)

You could try the following.  Intercept PageUp and PageDown key events.  Assuming your code gets the event first, use the return from scrollbar.get to calculate the top and bottom visible lines, use text.mark_set('insert', 'lineno.0') to make the cursor visible where you want it, and let the event propagate to move the text.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Xubuntu 14.04 (Linux). That probably accounts for the different behavior. It's good to know Windows is different there. I'm already intercepting the events and returning `"break"`; so I should be able to try out what you suggest without execution order problems. However, `Text.mark_set…` is what's bringing about the centering behavior, I think. Using `Text.see` with any index doesn't move the focus from it at all for some reason. I'll have to work on it and see if I can figure out what's going on and get back to you here.

Comment: Okay, apparently, using `Text.mark_set` doesn't center it if you only move one line, but it does if you move lots of lines. So, by going through a loop, doing it one line at a time, and calling `Text.see(INSERT)` in each iteration, it does what I want.